# How to create jquery data table from JSON array without declaring columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have following code which gets JSON from WebAPI.(for clarity of the question, I have defined the array as data from web API).

I need the data table to be dynamic and that's why I am creating the table headers at run time.

This works fine, but I do not see any data on data table and get the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tableId - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

```js
var data = [{
        "Number": "10031",
        "Description": "GYPROCK PLUS RE 10MM 1200X4200",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AA",
        "Quantity": 18
    },
    {
        "Number": "95844",
        "Description": "CEMINSEAL WALLBOARD RE 6MM 1350X3000",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AB",
        "Quantity": 6
    }
];

var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
var tr = $("<tr>");
$thead.append(tr);
$.each(data[0], function(name, value) {

    $(tr).append('<th>' + name + '</th>');
});

$('#tableId').DataTable({
    data: data,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/data/): _"The down side of using objects is that you need to explicitly tell DataTables which property it should use from the object for each column."_

Comment: did you need to show column name of json into table head

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya, Not really, but If I don't provide column name then there is a different error for sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    var data = [{
  "Number": "10031",
  "Description": "GYPROCK PLUS RE 10MM 1200X4200",
  "FarmLocation": "WH5",
  "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AA",
  "Quantity": 18
}, {
  "Number": "95844",
  "Description": "CEMINSEAL WALLBOARD RE 6MM 1350X3000",
  "FarmLocation": "WH5",
  "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AB",
  "Quantity": 6
}];

var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
var tr = $("<tr>");
$thead.append(tr);
var columns = [];
$.each(data[0], function(name, value) {
  var column = {
    "data": name,
    "title":name
  };
  columns.push(column);
});

$('#tableId').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: columns
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
  </table>
```

Maybe you can try to create the column from the data.
However, if the data is updated, I suppose you need to refresh the table in same way

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{
        "Number": "10031",
        "Description": "GYPROCK PLUS RE 10MM 1200X4200",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AA",
        "Quantity": 18
    },
    {
        "Number": "95844",
        "Description": "CEMINSEAL WALLBOARD RE 6MM 1350X3000",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AB",
        "Quantity": 6
    }
];

var headerData = data[0];
var columns = [];
var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
var tr = $("<tr>");
$thead.append(tr);
$.each(headerData, function(name, value) {
    $(tr).append('<th>' + name + '</th>');
   var obj = {'data': name};
   columns.push(obj);
   });
$('#tableId').DataTable({
    data: data,
    "columns": columns
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need for HTML manipulation or nasty jQuery. It can all be reduced to :

```html
<table id="tableId"></table>
```

```js
var table = $('#tableId').DataTable({
   data: data,
   columns: Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(item) {
     return { data: item, title: item }
   })
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/pz5hjv84/**

Comment: it's the best answer for the question, great.

Answer (score 0):

it is throwing the error as it not able to identify the names of the columns. So, you have to set the `columns` property of the `datatable.js` in order to display the data.

**Try the snippet below:**

```js
var data = [{
        "Number": "10031",
        "Description": "GYPROCK PLUS RE 10MM 1200X4200",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AA",
        "Quantity": 18
    },
    {
        "Number": "95844",
        "Description": "CEMINSEAL WALLBOARD RE 6MM 1350X3000",
        "FarmLocation": "WH5",
        "LocationIn": "LINE_1C2AB",
        "Quantity": 6
    }
];
let columns=[];
var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
var tr = $("<tr>");
$thead.append(tr);
$.each(data[0], function(name, value) {
    columns.push({data:name,name:name});
    $(tr).append('<th>' + name + '</th>');
});

$('#tableId').DataTable({
    data: data,
    "destroy": true,
    "columns":columns
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

for more information about the `columns` property please go through this link:
[datatable.js's columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)

> Update 1 use of dynamic column header

the `data` option of the `column` property is used to map the column to the given input data whereas the `name` property is used to set the display name for the field. Later on, the `destroy` property is used to refresh the `table`. For further detail on `destroy` [destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()).

Comment: Thanks vikscool, but the question clearly states , without declaring columns. In your answer you have declared columns