# How to generate table from incoming JSON data [Laravel, Ajax]

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a controller as `PostsController` and an Ajax which gets JSON data from the `PostsController` and I am able to show that JSON data in the table in blade view,  but problem is I have to statically declare the table column name and I want to make the table column name and field defined dynamically according to received JSON data.

The structure of the data is as follows:

```json
[
  'title': 'stackoverflow is awesome', 
  'body': 'stackoverflow is the top community for developers'
]
```

Now here I am trying to generate table column names and show these incoming data. What I am doing right now is just generating column rows like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435813/11040487), I think it is the same as what you are trying to do.